# Ov2640 pinout on board

Tags: microcontroller, camera

Hi guys I’m trying to find out which pins for ov2640 should connect to stm32F401RCT6 Specifically HRFF-PWDN -DCLK must insert in to board pinheader?can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the documentation of OV2640? Do you know what those pins (HRFF, PWDN, DCLK) do? Here is the datasheet, all pins and functions are there, see if makes anything a little more clear: https://www.uctronics.com/download/cam_module/OV2640DS.pdf, at least partially. For instance, PWDN is a power-down active high with internal pull-down, you can leave it disconnected if you don't need power-down mode.

Comment: No Idont know those pin what to do.  But the datasheet that you insert here is for camera chip with 38 pins for camera sensor and the module have just 18 pin and the most pins are different by camera chip with flat cable.

Comment: First of all, please delete your answer with a picture, because it doesn't have any solution/solution-related info, you could always send a link to the pic here in the comments if you want to show something. Second of all, we're talking about OV2640, and OV2640 is just an IC (chip), which is integrated into the module you have and which simply has some of its pins exposed (because other pins go to the camera piece itself). So all the info is actually there. For instance, about HRFF, which must be HREF in the datasheet, and which has a detailed explanation of what it does.